# In Scala, is it possible to use Plotly's Scatter3d?

Tags: scala, plot, plotly

My aim is to display points in a 3D space/chart/graph. In python, it seems to be possible : https://plot.ly/python/3d-scatter-plots/

But in Scala, I didn't find this object/class/trait :

1. The Web site speaks only about surfaces : https://plot.ly/scala/
2. The Plotly's documentation doesn't contain `Scatter3d` but only `Scatter`, which doesn't seem to support 3D : https://asidatascience.github.io/scala-plotly-client/latest/api/#co.theasi.plotly.Scatter
3. The `ThreeDPlot` class seems impossible to display points in 3D without drawing surfaces : https://asidatascience.github.io/scala-plotly-client/latest/api/#co.theasi.plotly.ThreeDPlot, and the set of Z-coordinates is strange (e.g. `Iterable[Iterable[Double]]` instead of something easier, e.g. `Iterable[Double]`)
4. The GitHub page's presentation use 3D points but display the only in a 2D space, by using only the X and Y coordinates : https://github.com/ASIDataScience/scala-plotly-client

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Scala Plotly, how to (correctly !) draw something in 3D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48365620/in-scala-plotly-how-to-correctly-draw-something-in-3d)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the latest version does not support 3D scatter plots yet.

However I've [forked the project](https://github.com/landlockedsurfer/scala-plotly-client) and added basic support for 3D scatter plots.
Here is an example that can be run directly from the sbt console:

```
val (x,y,z) = (Vector(1.0, 3.0, 3.0),Vector(2.0, 5.0, 1.0),Vector(5.0, 7.0, -1.0))
val p = ThreeDPlot().withScatter3D(x,y,z,ScatterOptions().copy(mode = Seq(ScatterMode.Marker)));
draw(p, "hello-plotly");
```

I've also opened [a pull request](https://github.com/ASIDataScience/scala-plotly-client/pull/37) so that the commit gets reviewed and possibly merged also.

Comment: This is now available in 0.3.0-SNAPSHOT of the Scala Plotly client -- see [this PR](https://github.com/ASIDataScience/scala-plotly-client/pull/38) for usage instructions. I'll release a new full release and update the documentation in the next few days.

Thanks to Landlocked Surfer for adding this!

Answer (score -2):

You may use [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) (most especially `mplot3d`)
Taking in consideration that `matplotlib` does not support natively Scala, you need to convert your scala data to matplotlib format before display and/or use [this module](https://github.com/vegas-viz/Vegas) which is:

> The missing MatPlotLib for Scala + Spark

Regards

Comment: I must use Plotly sorry